# Laravel error Column not found

Tags: php, laravel

Error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`id` = 1 limit 1)

I do have table 'products' with a 'product.id' field. Not sure why I am getting this error. I get this error when I

- access /product/{{product_id}}
- access /edit

Home Controller:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        return view('home')->with('products',$user->products);
    }
}
```

ProductController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\product;

class productController extends Controller
{
        /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth',['except' => ['index','show']]);
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = product::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(10);
        //$products = product::where('type','major')->get();
        return view('products.index')->with('products',$products);
    } 

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('products.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title' => 'required',
        ]);
            //create product
        $product = new product;
        $product->title = $request->input('title');
        $product->venue = $request->input('venue');
        $product->city = $request->input('city');
        $product->country = $request->input('country');
        $product->description = $request->input('description');
        $product->date = $request->input('date');
        $product->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $product->save();

        return redirect('/products')->with('success','product Created');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $product = product::find($id);
        return view('products.show');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $product = product::find($id);
        return view('products.edit')->with('product',$product);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required'
        ]);

        $product = product::find($id);
        $product->title = $request->input('title');
        $product->save();

        return redirect('/products')->with('success','product updated');
    }


    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $product = product::find($id);
        $product->delete();
        return redirect('/products')->with('success','product deleted');

    }
}
```

Show.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <h1 class="centre">{{$product->title}}</h1>

    <div class="well-xs">
        @if(!Auth::guest())
            @if(Auth::user()->id == $product->user_id)

                <a href="../products/{{$product->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>

                {!!Form::open(['action' => ['productcontroller@destroy', $product->product_id], 'method' => 'POST'])!!}
                    {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
                    {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
                {!!Form::close()!!}
            @endif
        @endif
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <h4>product Date: {{$product->date}}</h4>

            <h4>product Venue: {{$product->venue}}</h4>

            <h4>product Location:{{$product->city}}</h4>

            <h4>product Description: </h4>
            <p>{{$product->description}} </p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <hr>
    Written on 
    </hr>

</div>
@endsection
```

Products table schema: I added user_id manually in sql. migrate wasnt working when I tried making a separate migration to add_user_id_to_table

```
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('product_id');
        $table->string('title',200);
        $table->string('venue',200);
        $table->text('city',200);
        $table->text('country',200);
        $table->string('description');
        $table->date('date',200);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

user.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Product.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    //Table NAME
    protected $table = 'products';

    //PRIMARY KEY
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    //Timestamps
    public $timestamps =true;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: what's your db table schema ?

Comment: On which line does the error occur? Can you show your model classes?

Comment: share `User` model as well ?

Comment: The error says there is no `user_id` column in your `products` table

Comment: the error says that `products.user_id` not exists, and you'd shared your `events` table schema !

Comment: @hassan updated question to make it more clear

Comment: @ThomasRollet updated question to make it more clear

Comment: @user2486 updated question to make it more clear

Comment: @JorenV updated question to make it more clear

Comment: In your products table you have `public $primaryKey = 'id';` but your migration is using `product_id` as a key. You should use `id` as the primary auto-incrementing key. That's the convention.

Comment: @joem Can you put a screenshot of the table structure on the Mysql side?

Answer (score 0):

Change in your User model

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany("App\Product","product_id","product_id");
    //return $this->hasMany("App\Product","foreign_key","local_key");
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I have updated the question a little. Might make a difference. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @joem : Change your User model relation key

Answer (score -1):

When you modify your migrations, you still need to update the database. So you should try

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

That will erase your database and migrate it again

Also, you don't need to query for the current user in your controller

Instead of this:

```
public function index()
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $user = User::find($user_id);
    return view('home')->with('products',$user->products);
}
```

You can simply use:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('home')->with('products', auth()->user()->products);
}
```

EDIT:

Your products migration doesn't have a column called `id` defined but `product_id` instead.

Also, you're declaring a `belongsTo` relation in product to user while you don't have the id of the user on that table.

A relation `belongsTo` means that you have the id of the related model. For example

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Post::class);
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this-belongsTo(App\User::class); 
    }
}
```

This is possible because `posts` table has a field called `user_id`. Because a Post **belongs to** a user.

You don't need this code:

```
//Table NAME
protected $table = 'products';

//PRIMARY KEY
public $primaryKey = 'id';

//Timestamps
public $timestamps =true;
```

Laravel handle all of that automatically, you're defining the default values

Comment: Thanks :) I have updated the question a little. Might make a difference. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: ah still cant get it to work : im following this tutorial series by the way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42l4nHl_aUM